# How to add dynamic background color in ion-fab-button using ionic-v4?

Tags: ionic-framework, colors, ionic4

I am using the ionic 4 fab button, in the fab button I want to set a dynamic background color.

here example code:

> page.html

```
<!-- fab placed to the bottom end -->
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button [style.background.color]="currentColor" [style.color]="isColorLight(currentColor) ? 'black' : 'white'"
    size="small">
    <ion-icon name="color-palette"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="switchColor(i)" [style.background.color]="colors[i]"
      *ngFor="let color of colors; let i = index">
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

> page.ts

```
colors: string[] = ['#000000', '#db0f0f', '#0fbf0f', '#35a3e8', '#FFFFFF'];
currentColor: string = this.colors[0];
::
::
switchColor(index: number) {
  this.currentColor = this.colors[index];
}
```

Also, I try `[style.background-color]="currentColor"` but it is not working.

The output of @Najam Us Saqib answer:

[image]

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{'--background': currentColor}"` is the real answer. But `--background` will not work inside ngStyle attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The Color of the  is controlled by its `--ion-color-base` property. 
So please try using `--ion-color-base` also with the `!important` attribute to override already defined CSS attributes .

However when i tried with the `[ngstyle]` it did not work , to let it work i had to assign it through CSS file . I have added an example for your reference .

HTML template ,

```
<ion-fab-button color="light"  id="btnProceed"></ion-fab-button>
```

CSS chunk

> #btnProceed {
>          --ion-color-base: #006161 !important;
>              }

Hope this would help .

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngStyle] attribute.

```
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="start" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button [ngStyle]="{'background': currentColor}" [style.color]="isColorLight(currentColor) ? 'black' : 'white'"
    size="small">
    <ion-icon name="color-palette"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="switchColor(i)" [ngStyle]="{'background': currentColor}"
      *ngFor="let color of colors; let i = index">
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

Comment: Answer Updated please check Again.

Comment: check question I added the output of your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try "background" and not "background-color" like this :

[style.background]="currentColor"

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone sees this, i had the same problem and successfully managed to dynamically change the color by adding the [style] property, with the ionic-defined property --background:

```
<ion-fab-button
  [style.--background]="config.yourColor">
</ion-fab-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we need to change the background color of a shadow DOM, which is tricky to manipulate.

In this purpose, Ionic style this shadow DOM with [CSS properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab-button#css-custom-properties), which can be easily changed

- in CSS

```css
ion-fab-button {
    --background: #7c3aed
}
```

- in JS (dynamic)

```
<IonFabButton style={{ '--background': yourColor }} />;
```